# boot.632plus ROC and calibration statistic

Tags: r, roc, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have been trying to run my best glm (squirrel glider presence/absence~habitat variables) to determine the ROC and calibration slope statistic in RStudio (see example in tutorial link below). I have 80 sites with three habitat variables that I would like the ROC and calibration slope for.

I have been running my data as per this tutorial (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7603258/UOM-wintle-tutorial.zip) - See 3. Evaluation of predictive performance from paragraph "Now do a resampling evaluation"

My data is a generalized linear model

`<-glm(formula = sq_present ~ hbt+euc_species_richness+total_wattle,data=model.data, family=binomial)`

```
Sq present = (0,1), hbt = no. of trees / site, euc_species_richness = count (1-8), total_wattle = no. of trees / site
```

Problem is "boot.632plus" does not exist anymore. Is there a way to substitute the package with an upgraded version so I can use the same tutorial code?

I can provide my full data on request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In that zipped file I see a file named R 2.2.0.lnk. If that is the version of R for which that package was developed, then we are talking about paleo-computing. That was probably in current in 2004. You can still attempt running the code in the model_functions.R file, but the usual warranties apply. It anything breaks, .... you get to keep all the pieces.
     
I also do not find boot.632plus in the CRAN contributed Archive, so its provenance seems even more speculative.

Comment: Yes I can't seem to find the "boot.632plus" package anywhere, I did try downloading the version of R that the code was run in. I have decided to move on to another package! Thank you

Comment: The function `boot.632plus` was defined in the file `model_functions.R`. I  suspect that choosing models based on ROC or "calibration slope statistic" does not have a good theoretic underpinning, and that bootstrap methods were being substituted for good theory.